# get all soup above a certain div

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a soup of this format:

```
<div class = 'foo'>
  <table> </table>
  <p> </p>
  <p> </p>
  <p> </p>
  <div class = 'bar'>
  <p> </p>
  .
  .
</div>
```

I want to scrape all the paragraphs between the table and bar div. The challenge is that number of paragraphs between these is not constant. So I can't just get the first three paragraphs (it could be anywhere from 1-5).

How do I go about dividing this soup to get the the paragraphs. Regex seems decent at first, but it didn't work for me as later I would still need a soup object to allow for further extraction.

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select your element, iterate over its `siblings` and `break` if there is no `p`:

```
for t in soup.div.table.find_next_siblings():
    if t.name != 'p':
        break
    print(t)
```

or other way around and closer to your initial question - select the `<div class = 'bar'>` and `find_previous_siblings('p')`:

```
for t in soup.select_one('.bar').find_previous_siblings('p'):
    print(t)
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class = 'foo'>
  <table> </table>
  <p> </p>
  <p> </p>
  <p> </p>
  <div class = 'bar'>
  <p> </p>
  .
  .
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for t in soup.div.table.find_next_siblings():
    if t.name != 'p':
        break
    print(t)
```

###### Output

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If html as shown then just use :not to filter out later sibling p tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class = 'foo'>
  <table> </table>
  <p> </p>
  <p> </p>
  <p> </p>
  <div class = 'bar'>
  <p> </p>
  .
  .
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('.foo > table ~ p:not(.bar ~ p)')
```